# Does running/biking suffice as a leg workout?

Tags: running, muscle, strength-training, legs

I'm currently overweight and have been doing the 5x5 program pretty consistently but want to integrate more cardio into my workout plan. After jogging, my legs/knees feel pretty tired as it is and am afraid of hurting my knee (already have a torn ACL). Does jogging/running suffice as a leg workout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please use low-impact exercises till you are fit enough to run. A lot of people make the mistake of using running as an exercise to get fit which can backfire.

1. Rowing - Uses upper body as well and low on impact.
2. Ellipticals - Again relatively low impact
3. Spinning - Relatively Low impact

You are doing good in following 5x5, please continue that and build on strength and with calorie deficit you will lower body fat. Patience is the key!

Comment: Is this done in parallel with running or no running?

Comment: @Steven Do not run till you have gained sufficient strength and reduced your weight. You need to be fit to run and not other way round. The recommended exercise will take good care of your cardio-vascular conditioning.